# Problem with the Caesar cipher when using a special character not in the alphabet

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have finished my Caesar cipher code, now I run into the problem of not being able to get the `z` instead of the `|`. I use US-ASCII.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main {
    final String GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN = "Werden zwei Glasstaebe mit einem Wolltuch gerieben, dann kann man feststellen, dass sich die beiden Staebe gegenseitig abstossen. Wird das gleiche Experiment mit zwei Kunststoffstaeben wiederholt, dann bleibt das Ergebnis gleich, auch diese beiden Staebe stossen sich gegenseitig ab. Im Gegensatz dazu ziehen sich ein Glas und ein Kunststoffstab gegenseitig an. Diese mit den Gesetzen der Mechanik nicht zu erklaerende Erscheinung fuehrt man auf Ladungen zurueck. Da sowohl Anziehung als auch Abstossung auftritt, muessen zwei verschiedene Arten von Ladungen existieren. Man unterscheidet daher positive und negative Ladungen.";
    final String ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE = "ugjt iwv! fw jcuv fgp eqfg igmpcemv wpf fkt uq twjo wpf gjtg gtyqtdgp. ykg fw ukgjuv, kuv fkgugu xgtuejnwguugnwpiuxgthcjtgp ugjt ngkejv |w mpcemgp. mqornk|kgtvgtg xgthcjtgp ygtfgp kp cpfgtgp xgtcpuvcnvwpigp pcgjgt dgvtcejvgv.";
    private static final char SEPARATOR = ' ';


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {1, 3, 5, 7, 3};
        // int[] values2 = {4, 0, 3, 4, 10};
        int maxIndex = getIndexOfMaximumEntry(values);
        System.out.println(maxIndex);
        CaesarChiffre caesarChiffre = new CaesarChiffre();

        // Get the histogram of the German language pattern
        int[] histogram = getHistogram(caesarChiffre.GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN);

        // Find the index of the maximum entry in the histogram
        int significantIndex = getIndexOfMaximumEntry(histogram);

        // Get the character at the significantIndex
        char significantLetter = (char) significantIndex;

        // Calculate quantity and quota
        int quantity = histogram[significantIndex];
        double quota = ((double) quantity / caesarChiffre.GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN.length()) * 100;

        // Print the results
        System.out.println("Most significant letter: " + significantLetter);
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + quantity + " times (" + quota + "% of the whole text).");

        // Return the significant letter
        char result = getSignificantLetter(caesarChiffre.GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN);

        // b) Get the significant letters for the encrypted text and language pattern
        char sigOfChiffre = getSignificantLetter(caesarChiffre.ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE);
        char sigOfPattern = getSignificantLetter(caesarChiffre.GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN);

        // c) Calculate the shift
        int shift = sigOfChiffre - sigOfPattern;

        // d) Print the intermediate decoding results
        System.out.println("Most significant letter in the pattern text: " + sigOfPattern);
        System.out.println("Most significant letter in the encrypted text: " + sigOfChiffre);
        System.out.println("Resulting shift: " + shift);

        // e) Return the shift
        System.out.println("Result of getShift: " + shift);

        // 7. Call the decode method from the main method
        String decodedText = decode(caesarChiffre.ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE, caesarChiffre.GERMAN_LANGUAGE_PATTERN);

        // 8. Print the encrypted and decoded texts
        System.out.println("Unreadable, encrypted input text:");
        System.out.println(caesarChiffre.ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Readable, decoded output text:");
        System.out.println(decodedText);

        // 9. Add a comment with the decrypted text and the key to the end of the main method
        // Decrypted text: [Your decrypted text]
        // Key: Shifted by 2
    }

    public static int[] getHistogram(String text) {
        int[] histogram = new int[128];
        String[] words = text.split(String.valueOf(SEPARATOR));
        for (String word : words) {
            String lowercaseWord = word.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < lowercaseWord.length(); i++) {
                char c = lowercaseWord.charAt(i);
                histogram[c]++;
            }
        }
        return histogram;
    }

    public static int getIndexOfMaximumEntry(int[] values) {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] > values[maxIndex]) {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    public static char getSignificantLetter(String text) {
        int[] histogram = getHistogram(text);
        int significantIndex = getIndexOfMaximumEntry(histogram);
        return (char) significantIndex;
    }

    public static int getShift(String encryptedText, String languagePattern) {
        char sigOfChiffre = getSignificantLetter(encryptedText);
        char sigOfPattern = getSignificantLetter(languagePattern);
        return sigOfChiffre - sigOfPattern;
    }

    // f) Method to decode the text
    // f) Method to decode the text
    public static String decode(String encryptedText, String languagePattern) {
        // g) Get the shift value
        int shift = getShift(encryptedText, languagePattern);

        // h) Convert encryptedText to char array
        char[] lettersEncryptedText = encryptedText.toCharArray();

        // i) Shift characters in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersEncryptedText.length; i++) {
            char c = lettersEncryptedText[i];

            // Check if the character is an ASCII letter or a printable character
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                // Adjust the shift calculation for both uppercase and lowercase letters
                char base = (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? 'a' : 'A';
                lettersEncryptedText[i] = (char) ((c - shift - base + 26) % 26 + base);
            }
        }

        // j) Convert the char array to a String
        String decoded = new String(lettersEncryptedText);

        // Return the decoded text
        return decoded;
    }


    }
```

I need

```
sehr gut! du hast den code geknackt und dir so ruhm und ehre erworben. wie du siehst, ist dieses verschluesselungsverfahren sehr leicht zu knacken. kompliziertere verfahren werden in anderen veranstaltungen naeher betrachtet.
```

instead of

```
sehr gut! du hast den code geknackt und dir so ruhm und ehre erworben. wie du siehst, ist dieses verschluesselungsverfahren sehr leicht |u knacken. kompli|iertere verfahren werden in anderen veranstaltungen naeher betrachtet.
```

Comment: Please always try and post code that we can run out of the box, an [mce]. Did you check if you get the same text if you encrypt with the same code for encryption? Remember: GIGO; If you have `|` as input character... Step through the code with a debugger. If you don't see too much, try to split the encryption code: for each char convert to index, then perform modular addition or subtraction, then convert back to character.

Comment: Can you, please, format the part of your code from `public class CaesarChiffre` to `public static void main` ?

Comment: Considering the `|` is in the `ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE`, your decryption code might actually be correct. Have you considered the problem is in the code that created `ENCRYPTED_MESSAGE`?

Comment: The | should be translated to lowercase z, since shift = 2 should do that. Somehow that doesnt work though

Comment: Oh, I meant an [mre], sorry, SE acronyms are not always those you'd expect.

Comment: The simple answer `if (Character.isLetter(c))` restricts decryption to work only on letters. You could add a special case to deal with `|`: `if (c == '|') {...} else if (Character.isLetter(c)) { ... }`. But, I suspect if you did that, you might have to expand it to deal with `[`,```,`]`.`^`,`_`,`{`,`}`,`~` as well. My guess is `if (Character.isLetter(c))` is actually correct, and the problem is at the encryption end: `z` was mistakenly converted to `|` when it should have been converted to `b`.

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example.  This works for uppercase values only.

```java
String encrypt(char[] a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, c, m = a.length; i < m; i++) {
        c = a[i];
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
        if ((a[i] = (char) (c + n)) > 'Z') a[i] -= 26;
    }
    return new String(a);
}

String decrypt(char[] a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, c, m = a.length; i < m; i++) {
        c = a[i];
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
        if ((a[i] = (char) (c - n)) < 'A') a[i] += 26;
    }
    return new String(a);
}
```

Output

```
encrypt = QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD
decrypt = THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

Comment: Writing a solution from scratch doesn’t do much to help the author of the question.  And any answer containing code should explain what was changed and why.

Comment: This code does not address the issue of a non-alphabetic character, specifically a `|`, in the encrypted data, so does not address the concern of the author of the question. Other than that, the author of the question has already demonstrated code that can do what this `decrypt` method does.